# Flappy bird screen flash when you die? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, flappy-bird-clone

When you collide with a pipe in Flappy Bird, an extremely brief white flash fills the screen. How can I reproduce this in my own game? It almost resembles the same white flash that occurs when you take a screen shot, but it's much shorter in duration. How can I reproduce this short flash of white light? This code would obviously go inside of my if died == true statement, just asking about the code that would go inside of it to make the white flash.

Comment: Can you please give us some more information?  What frameworks is the game made with?  What code have you tried, and what was the problem with it?

Comment: I haven't tried any code. I just need the code that produces a short flash of white on the screen. I'm using SpriteKit. @NobodyNada

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Create a SKShapeNode with the size of screen.
- Make its backgroundColor to be white.
- Add a SKAnimation, change the alpha from 0 to 1 then from 1 to 0.

done.